# Passing form input values as a List of objects from a JSP page to a Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, backing-beans

Here is a **simplified** (NOT real world) example. Suppose there is a domain model - a class *Movie*, which has a List of actors. A class *Actor* has three fields (*name*, *birthDate*, *rolesNumber*). The following code is an illustration of this scenario:

*Movie.java*

```
public class Movie {

    // some fields

    private List<Actor> actors;

    // getters and setters
}
```

*Actor.java*

```
public class Actor {

    private String name;

    private Date birthDate;

    private int rolesNumber;

    // getters and setters
}
```

There is also a JSP page where we output in a loop the information about every actor that plays in a concrete movie and the user can **update the corresponding text field values** and submit changes to a servlet:

*actorsUpdate.jsp*

```
...
<c:forEach items="${movie.actors}" var="actor">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <td><input type="text" value="${actor.name}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Birth Date</th>
            <td><input type="text" value="${actor.birthDate}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Number of Previous Roles</th>
            <td><input type="text" value="${actor.rolesNumber}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr />
</c:forEach>
...
```

It is known that in order to retrieve text fields in a servlet, one can use *ServletRequest's* methods like [`getParameter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) or [`getParameterValues()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) etc. But how to retrieve the updated input fields as a List of objects (so that every three related values were grouped)?

If it were Spring project we could use Spring's `<form:form modelAttribute="modelName">`
tag and have a **backing object** defined in the *modelAttribute*. But how about pure JSP/Servlet project?

## Possible solution

One of the possible solutions is to assign names in the "*name*" attribute of the text inputs and append *varStatus.index*, like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${movie.actors}" var="actor" varStatus="counter">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="name${counter.index}" value="${actor.name}" /></td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </table>
    <hr />
</c:forEach>
```

So this index would allow us to **identify values related to ONE object**. And we could also generate some hidden input field where we could store a *loop count* (a number of actors), and then in a servlet we could retrieve the values related to one object like this:

```java
List<Actor> actors= new ArrayList<Actor>();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    String name= request.getParamater("name" + i);
    Date birthDate = dateFormat.parse(request.getParamater("birthDate" + i));
    int rolesNumber = Integer.parseInt(request.getParamater("rolesNumber" + i));

    Actor actor = new Actor(name, birthDate, rolesNumber);
    actors.add(actor);
}
```

---

### My questions are:

1. Is there another, more elegant and effective way of passing the updated text field values to a servlet as a **List of objects**?
2. Is there any solution **similar or equivalent** to that of the Spring's `<form:form>` tag in a world of pure JSP/JSTL/EL/Servlets?

---

## UPDATE

Looks like nobody knows the answer to the above questions. The accepted answer is not exactly what I asked for (see my comments to it).

There seems to be no equivalent of Spring's `<form:form modelAttribute>` tag or something similar in the world of pure Servlets/JSP.

Well, full [Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html), or [Spring Framework](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/), [Apache Struts](http://struts.apache.org/) or another powerful [web application framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework) to the rescue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the same name(revisionNumber) for all the inputs and use

`String[] revisionNumber = request.getParamaterValues("revisionNumber")`  to get an array.

Comment: But how to be sure that, for example, the concrete "revisionNumber" is related to concrete "revisionDate" and concreate "comment". In my example, three above mentioned fields relate to ONE Detail object. I know about picking values as an array, just wanted to know if there is some way to MAKE SURE that each of those three fields get retrieved as a group.

Comment: Or they will be definitely collected in the order? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning this to a jsp page, it is advisable that you display it in a list directly by returning the object actors to the list directly. set it in your code to the session from the class, session.setAttribute("actorsList", actors);

Then in your JSP page, the list would be like this. (actorsList is the object set, you name it a name like act, then you can set a first initial static field in the list in option, and the list will loop on the getProperty to get the property "name" from your object.

```
<ffi:list collection="actorsList" items="act">
  <option value="">(Select An Actor)</option>
  <ffi:getProperty name="act" property="name"/>
</ffi:list>
```