# How to post an array of hidden fields to a servlet?

Tags: java, html, forms, servlets, post

```
<form>
<c:forEach var="cartitems" items="${cart.items}">
<input type="hidden" name="productid[]" value="${cartitems.products.productsId}">
</c:forEach>
</form>
```

Above code will generates HTML code like

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="productid[]">
<input type="hidden" value="5" name="productid[]">
```

How do I access these values in servlet, somthing which I have tried but it does not works:

```
  String[] productsids = request.getParameterValues("productid");
for(String eachpro  : productsids){
  out.println("Product values : "+eachpro);
}
```

Is there any other way to do this work

Comment: Which Above code will generate which HTML code?

Comment: Close your `<input />` fields correctly, if you aren't doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is absolutely no problem with getting the hidden input elements' values as an array** in `doPost()` method with `request.getParameterValues()`.

But **in your example you have an error**: for your hidden input you have set `name="productid[]"`, but when retrieving the values you used

`request.getParameterValues("productid")`;

i.e. **without** index operator `[]` at the end.

**I have just tested** getting multiple hidden values populated with `<c:forEach>` on my machine and I am getting all those hidden results in the `doPost()` method using `` `request.getParameterValues("productid[]") `` **without any problem**.

So just check everything, it seems you are doing something wrong somewhere.

---

### Some unrelated notes concerning naming conventions

1. In Java web development, unlike PHP, it is not common to use index
   operator `[]` at the end of the name for an `input` or any other HTML
   element inside JSP, like you did for `productid[]`, although it works fine. So giving a name for your hidden  input element like
   `<input type="hidden" name="productId" value="123" />`
   would be more natural/common. But again it is *your choice*.
2. In `<c:forEach>` tag it would be much more intuitive to give a
   value for the `var` attribute using **singular**, plus using camelCase
   would also be more *Java way*, like
   `<c:forEach var="cartItem" items="${cart.items}">`

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works, when I add [] with request.getParameterValues("productid[]"), but I would also like to now what we do commonly in java for a cart where having multiple products and their quantity, something which I have also seen [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784402/passing-text-field-values-as-a-list-from-a-jsp-page-to-a-servlet  revisionNumber${counter.index} adding a counter with field name  , but don't looks like a professional way, any other idea with java?

Comment: Not sure if I get you correctly, but commonly, for the repeated/similar HTML elements (like in your example), just **use the same name** and then retrieve those values with `request.getParameterValues()` as an array. Again, like in your case: `<input type="hidden" name="productId" value="1" /> <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="2" />` and then in `doPost()` method retieve them: `String[] productIds = request.getParameterValues("productId");`

Comment: btw I posted an answer to your question: [Need a book for learning step by step MVC shopping cart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254288/need-a-book-for-learning-step-by-step-mvc-shopping-cart-development-using-servle/16255895#16255895). Check out the The NetBeans E-commerce Tutorial there, the whole source code is also available for download. You can see this web app live here: http://services.netbeans.org/AffableBean/. But it is better to download the source code and deploy it locally, because the online version is not fully functional (not access to the *Admin console* and *checkout*)

Comment: And in the source code of the E-Commerce Tutorial you can see, how its shopping cart works, how items are added and so on. Also download the source code for the "Murach's Java Servlets and JSP, 2nd Edition" (again see my answer to your "Need a book..." question) which has the Music Store web app. It also has chopping cart and all the related stuff.

Comment: thanks for your help, I had seem music store example and also I have seen glashfish's book. but I was not able to try netbeans example, before that post was deleted, eventhough I was not able to thank you, sorry but again I am very glad with your help and support, I think with your support I will be able to dive into Java world.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the subscript from the name field of Input Tag & use the same in the getParameterValues on the server side. The name of the parameter should be same for retrieving the values of a field on the server side.

(Change name of the input from `productid[]` to "`productid`)

```
<form>
   <c:forEach var="cartitems" items="${cart.items}">
       <input id = "${cartitems.products.productsId}" type="hidden" name="productid" value="${cartitems.products.productsId}">
   </c:forEach>
</form>
```

Comment: no it does not works, it only gives a single value - first hidden field's value <input type="hidden" value="1" name="productid">, any other idea?

Comment: Aaan!!! Did you define an action in your form tag? I don't see a submit action either. How are you sending request to the servlet?

Comment: <form action="testcontroller" id="updateForm" method="post">, it is posting perfectly, but as I can see if I remove [] from productid, according to HTML there is 2 entities with duplicate name, so it will always take value of first one, in this way it is only giving first hidden field's value. any other way of doing this?

Comment: Basically I am a PHP developer and it works perfectly with PHP, and I have also seen some where the above idea of posting multiple values is invention of PHP, so I wanted to know how I can do this with servlets?

Comment: Can you try changing the type of the input field from hidden to checkbox, and tell me if it is still behaving similarly?

Comment: Yes, if I change it to checkbox with [] it works perfectly, but not with hidden field, but I can not put checkbox, this it is a shopping cart's cart page.

Comment: Please add ID attribute to the input and then try. I have modified the code in the answer.

Comment: Actually, removing `[]` doesn't play any role: `request.getParameterValues("productid[]")` works fine, *although* it is not common in Java web development to give such names for the HTLM elements, it is more PHP way.